# Moving items in qml treeview

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qml, qtquick2

I have Qt Quick treeview connected to my *QAbstractItemModel* by exposing it through *setContextProperty* and it works well.
Now I want to be able to change the order of the items (in the view and the model) by dragging them up and down. I've created DropArea

```
DropArea {
        anchors { fill: parent; margins: 10 }

        onEntered: {
           // ???
        }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to implement moving in qml. In qwidget approach it's handled by removeRows/insertRows. What's the correct approach in qt quick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct approach would be to use the model and either move items, or remove/insert them into the new location. Since those functions are not directly exposed to QML, you will have to expose them through wrapper slots, for example in your model.

When you modify the source model, the view will automatically adjust to reflect the changes.

Comment: how could I get previous and new position?

Comment: @amplifier - you can use the `QModelIndex indexAt(int x, int y)` model of the view, respectively for your drag source and drop target.

Comment: is "indexAt" the only way to get "from" and "to" indices?